# get sum based on another field django

Tags: django, django-models

I have these models:

```
status_choices = ['not received', 'received']

class Investment(Model):
    # Offering
    offering = models.ForeignKey(Offering, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invested = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, default=0, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=status_choices, blank=True, null=True, default='not received')
    
class Offering(Model):
    
    ...
```

I want to make a property to display the sum of all investments inside the `Offering` model.

I did so like this:

```
    @property
    def amount_invested(self):
        return Investment.objects.filter(offering_id=self.id).aggregate(Sum('invested'))['invested__sum'] or 0
```

But, I also want to display the `amount_invested` iff the `status` inside the `Investment` model is `'received'`.

May I know how I should be able to do this?

Comment: So you only want to sum the `invested` with `status='received'`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, just received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `investment_set` and thus only retain the `Investment`s with `status='received'`:

```
@property
def amount_invested(self):
    return self.investment_set.filter(
        status='received'
    ).aggregate(Sum('invested'))['invested__sum'] or 0
```

Comment: thanks, but what if there are multiple statuses that I need to check on? I just put received but there are status_1, status_2.

Comment: @ProsyArceno: you use `status__in=['status_1', 'status_2']`.